# Fastest way to search and sort vectors

Tags: c++

I'm doing a project in which i need to insert data into vectors sort it and search it ...

i need fastest possible algorithms for sort and search ... i've been searching and found out that std::sort is basically quicksort which is one of the fastest sorts but i cant figure out which search algorithm is the best ? binarysearch?? can u help me with it? tnx ... So i've got 3 methods:

```
void addToVector(Obj o)
{
  fvector.push_back(o);
}

void sortVector()
{
  sort(fvector.begin(), fvector().end());
}

Obj* search(string& bla)
{
 //i would write binary search here
 return binarysearch(..);
}
```

Comment: Binary search is the standard "fast" search for an array or vector

Comment: Use std::sort and after it std::binary_search and you are fine.

Comment: Does the vector have to be sorted, or can you use another (unsorted) data-structure with amortised O(1)?

Comment: `std::lower_bound` and `std::upperbound` are implemented via binary search.

Comment: @40two: Oddly enough, `std::binary_search` is completely useless because it doesn't do what you'd think.  `std::lower_bound` is what you're thinking of.

Comment: @MooingDuck interesting, sadly enough it seems theoretical standards don't hold for quite some cases in STL. Do you have citations on the issue? P.S thanks a lot for the constructive comment.

Comment: @40two: The C++ spec, and cppreference.com both make it clear, and even the return type of `bool` clarifies that `std::binary_search` doesn't do what you'd hope it does, instead it merely tells you if the item was found or not.  The documentation of `std::lower_bound` clarifies that it's what you would use to find an element via binary search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

---

> - **I've been searching and found out that [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) is basically
>     quicksort.**
>
>   > > **Answer:** Not quite. Most implementations use a [hybrid algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_algorithm) like 
>   > >       [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which combines [quick-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), [heap-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) and [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

---

> - **Quick-sort is one of the fastest sorting methods.**
>
>   > > **Answer:** Not quite. In general it holds (i.e., in the average case quick-sort is of [image] complexity). However, quick-sort has quadratic worst-case performance (i.e., [image]). Furthermore, for a small number of inputs (e.g., if you have a `std::vector` with a small numbers of elements) sorting with quick-sort tends to achieve worst performance than other sorting algorithms that are considered "slower" (see chart below):

[image]

---

> - **I can't figure out which searching algorithm is the best. Is it binary-search?**
>
>   > > **Answer:** [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) has the same average and worst case performance (i.e., [image]). Also have in mind that binary-search requires that the container should be arranged in ascending or descending order. However, whether is better than other searching methods (e.g., [linear search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) which has [image] time complexity) depends on a number of factors. Some of them are:
>   > >
>   > > 1. The number of elements/objects (see chart below).
>   > > 2. The type of elements/objects.

[image]

---

> **Bottom Line:**
>
> - Usually looking for the "fastest" algorithm denotes premature optimization and according to one of the "great ones" (*Premature optimization is the root of all evil - [Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DonKnuth)*). The "fastest", as I hope it has been clearly shown, depends on quite a number of factors.
> - Use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to sort your [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).
> - After sorting your [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) use [`std::binary_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) to find out whether a certain element exists in your [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or use [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) or [`std::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) to find and get an element from your [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: Good point but IMHO oversimplifies the problem. Number of elements is not only factor that affects sorting speed.

Comment: @Slava thanks a lot, in the bottom line though I mention also "other factors".

Comment: use `std::lower_bound` to search your `std::vector`.  `binary_search` merely tells you that an element exists.  Also, your sorting graph makes it look like binary search is faster for all numbers of elements.  Zoom it in a bit so it's clearer that for small numbers it's not always best.

Comment: @MooingDuck would you be kind enough as to check the updated answer?

Answer (score 3):

For amortised O(1) access times, use a [`[std::unordered_map]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), maybe using a custom hash for best effects.
Sorting seems to be unneccessary extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Searching and Sorting efficiency is highly dependent on the type of data, the ordering of the raw data, and the quantity of the data.

For example, for small sorted data sets, a linear search may be faster than a binary search; or the time differences between the two is negligible.

Some sort algorithms will perform horribly on inversely ordered data, such a binary tree sort.  Data that does not have much variation may cause a high degree of collisions on hash algorithms.

Perhaps you need to answer the bigger question:  Is search or sorting the execution bottleneck in my program?  Profile and find out.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the fastest or the best sorting algorithm... There is no such one. At least it haven't been found yet. There are algorithms that provide better results for different data, there are algorithms that provide good results for most of data. You either need to analyze your data and find the best one for your case or use generic algo like std::sort and expect it to provide good results but not the best.

Answer (score 0):

if your elements are of integer you should use bucket sort algorithm which run at O(N) time instead of O(nlogn) average case as with qsort
[[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort%5d)

Answer (score 0):

#### Sorting

In case you want to know about the fastest sorting technique for integer values in a vector then I would suggest you to refer the following link:
https://github.com/fenilgmehta/Fastest-Integer-Sort

It uses radix sort and counting sort for large arrays and merge sort along with insertion sort for small arrays.
According to statistics, this sorting algorithm is way faster than C++ std::sort for integral values.

It is 6 times faster than C++ STL std::sort for "int64_t array[10000000]"

#### Searching

If you want to know whether a particular value is present in the vector or not, then you should use [binary_search(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search)

If you want to know the exact location of an element, then use [lower_bound(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [upper_bound(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)