# Most efficient way to sort one element in a vector?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a vector of elements which are sorted based some external value. It is a large container and looking up the sort-value is relatively expensive. At some point one element (only) needs to be re-sorted. What is the most efficient way to just re-sort that element? `std::sort()` the vector? erase-insert the element? compare the element to its immediate neighbours?

EDIT: to clarify, by erase-insert the element I mean something like this:

```
// erase the key and then insert-sort it
auto iter = std::find(keys.begin(), keys.end(), key);

keys.erase(iter);
SortedInsert(keys, index, <cmp>);
```

EDIT2: the container needs to be a vector for other performance reasons

Comment: Do you mean to insert one value into an existing sorted vector?

Comment: The worst case is O(n) complexity (the one element gets moved from the end to the beginning) - you probably want another data structure (maybe `std::set`?)

Comment: For the argument of sorted `vector` vs. `set`, an interesting article: http://asawicki.info/news_1352_the_beauty_of_sorted_arrays.html

Comment: Since you ask how to do it fast, I assume you're going to do it often enough to make a difference. In this case you should work around this because it *will* be slow. For example, you can have additional non-sorted vector, which after it will be large enough, you'll reorganize it into your sorted vector - the large cost is amortized over many insertions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert an element directly at the right place in a sorted vector, you should use `upper_bound` to get an iterator and pass it to `insert` to place the element at the right place:

```
vec.insert(std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), item), item);
```

Note that `upper_bound` will be fast (`O(log n)`) but inserting can be slow (`O(n)`) because it will have to shift all the elements that are after the insertion point.

However, inserting at the end of the vector and calling `std::sort` is `O(n log n)` so it's worst, at least on big vectors !

```
vec.insert(item);
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Another option could be to insert at the end of the vector and then shift with previous element until it's lower or equal. In this case, the insert is amortized `O(1)` and you have to do `O(n)` swaps.

I'm afraid there won't be an `O(log n)` solution as you could have with a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end)
```

Consider it`s part of STL and it`s well implemented.

Comment: No, his vector is already sorted and he just wants to put one value at the right place so it's not the most efficient

Comment: Then a binary search will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing the values in a MAP instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the answer of [101010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548336/fastest-way-to-search-and-sort-vectors). I think it is very explanatory. You can analyse this with your case.