# Fastest way to sort a data structure in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std

I have a data structure that consists of three `int` values that represent a coordinate, and a `double` that represents a value at that coordinate. I would like to store them together, and sort them on value. Values are not unique. Right now, I have them in a `struct` and I sort them using a lambda, as is shown in the code below. As this is a piece of performance-critical code, I am looking for an implementation that gives the fastest sorting. The list will contain 10^6 to 10^7 elements.

What is the most elegant way to solve this? I am not trying to use `std::sort`, but I am mostly asking whether to store the data in a `struct` is the best solution, or are there better alternatives?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Data
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    double d;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> v;

    v.push_back({1,2,3,0.6});
    v.push_back({1,2,3,0.2});
    v.push_back({1,2,3,0.5});
    v.push_back({1,2,3,0.1});
    v.push_back({1,2,3,0.4});

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const Data& a, const Data& b)
            { return a.d < b.d; });

    for (auto d : v)
        std::cout << d.i << ", " << d.j << ", "
                  << d.k << ", " << d.d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to learn what is wrong with my question.

Comment: "Fastest way to sort" is almost the definition of too-broad. It depends on far too many things: your compiler and options, your target system architecture, the number of elements to be sorted, how the elements are arranged prior to sorting. You'll most likely have to implement a few algorithms and run performance tests yourself using real data

Comment: and 99% of the time, the answer is "you can write and debug this several hundred line file, and it will be on average half a percent faster than `std::sort`".  Just use `std::sort`.

Comment: Depends on `how fast` do you need it to be and on how many data sets you want to perform the sort on? If you need it to be fast, I would recommend storing the `double` in a separate container along with its original index in the vector. Thi would enable more elements to be loaded in the cache while sorting. But, accessing the vector elements later might worsen the performance by a bit due to random access via the index. So, it all depends on what you really want.

Comment: @MooingDuck. I do want to use `std::sort`, I doubt about the `struct`

Comment: @Chiel if the sorting is only done on the field `d` and does not use `i`, `j`, or `k` then you *may* get an advantage by reordering `i`, `j`, and `k` into another structure that `Data` points to. This would reduce some copying overhead. However the advantage here would be negligible and would make other operations much slower.

Comment: With a custom compare function, std::stable_sort() (assuming it's based on some variation of merge sort) might be a bit faster). Assuming you're using an optimizing compiler, writing your own sort will probably only reduce sort time by less than 10%. 10^7 structures should only take a few seconds to sort.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to sort them is to not have to sort them.

At the expense of some slightly slower insertion, you could store your entire container sorted, and insert only in the correct place.  A [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) could help you here, or you could roll your own.

**edit:**  A [std::multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) would provide the same advantages if you need to allow values that compare equal.

Comment: I did not know that one. Thanks

Comment: I'd point out that it also depends on use.  If you would normally populate your structure and then sort once before use, then this would possibly be less efficient than a fill and sort.  If you will be sorting regularly in code, this will probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Question, [Fastest way to search and sort vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548336/fastest-way-to-search-and-sort-vectors) is a far better answer than I could give.

Summary, 
You need a better sample set, 5 entries isn't going to tell you anything. You're not going to be able to beat std::sort. In particular to you, the floating point compare will be the painful bit.

Comment: I do want to use sort, I am mostly doubting whether the `struct` is the correct datatype, or whether I should use a `std::pair` for instance.